# Comparator using a String field of my class for comparison?

Tags: java, string, comparator

I have a list of objects of type A, and I have to order it for a field of A, which is of type String.

```
public class A{
    public String field1;
    public Integer field2;
    ...
}
```

If I had to order for the int field would have done so:

```
Collections.sort(listOfA, new Comparator<A>() {
        public int compare(A p1, A p2) {
            return p1.field2 - p2.field2);
            }
        });
```

But unfortunately need to order by the field of type String.

How can I do this?

Comment: Using subtraction in a `compareTo` method is in general dangerous because of integer overflows. Use `Ints.compare` from Google's Guava instead.

Comment: @Roland or just `>` `=` and `<`

Comment: Yes, but in the case of `<=>` you have to spell out the operators and the result explicitly. I find it easier to just write `return Ints.compare(a, b)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    public int compare(A p1, A p2) {
        return p1.field2.compareTo( p2.field2) );
        }
```

Comment: And the Class A has to implement the Comparable<A> Interface

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively your class could implement interface [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), like this

```
public class A implements Comparable<A> {
  public String field1;
  public Integer flied2;

    public int compareTo(A o) {
        return this.field1.compareTo(o.field1);
    }

}
```

Which would allow you to

```
Collections.sort(listofA);
```

Which IMO is preferable/cleaner if A's are always sorted by field1.

Answer (score 1):

You could use String [compareTo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, nevertheless.
With java 8, you now have lambdas:

```
listOfA.sort((a,b) -> a.field1.compareTo(b.field1));
```

Also, if one had a getter for field1, which one probably should, you could also then do

```
listOfA.sort(Comparator.comparing(A::getFieldOne));
```

If you don't have a getter, there's also this:

```
listOfA.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.field1));
```