# Can´t find the mistake in this code, Comparator

Tags: java, comparator

I have this class that implements the comparator method in a JFrame, for some reason when u put the same name twice the program falls and print this -->
StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

The code of the method:

```
public class OrdenarCrecienteTecnico implements Comparator<Tecnico> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Tecnico a, Tecnico b) {
        String PalabraA = a.getNombre().toUpperCase();
        String PalabraB = b.getNombre().toUpperCase();
        int i = 0;
    while(i<PalabraA.length() && i<PalabraB.length() && PalabraA.charAt(i) == PalabraB.charAt(i)){    
        i++;
    }
    return PalabraA.charAt(i) - PalabraB.charAt(i);
}
```

}

Comment: Why write code like that? Use `PalabraA.compareTo(PalabraB)` instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparator using a String field of my class for comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890006/comparator-using-a-string-field-of-my-class-for-comparison)

Comment: The `char` type is obsolete, and cannot be used to compare strings in that manner.

Answer (score 1):

This code, when faced with identical strings,

```
while(i<PalabraA.length() && i<PalabraB.length() && PalabraA.charAt(i) == PalabraB.charAt(i)){    
    i++;
}
```

will fall out of the loop with `i` equal to the length of the string. Then you execute this:

```
return PalabraA.charAt(i) - PalabraB.charAt(i);
```

which is guaranteed to throw an out-of-bounds exception, because valid indexes run from 0 to length-1.

Answer (score 0):

[This other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65054895/642706) describes your specific problem and solution.

You seem to be working too hard. Simply let the two strings do the comparison.

```java
public class OrdenarCrecienteTecnico implements Comparator<Tecnico> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Tecnico a, Tecnico b) {
        if( Objects.isNull( a ) || Objects.isNull( b ) ) { return -1 ; }
        return a.getNombre().compareToIgnoreCase( a.getNombre() ) ;

}
```

Comment: equalsIgnoreCase returns a boolean, right?